# high (photoshop/illustrator) quality text through .net platform

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to generate text to print out in a .net application that matches what our designers are able to produce in Photoshop & Illustrator. Using the built-in drawing API's from GDI+ can't produce the same type of output when it comes to anti-aliasing, kerning/letter spacing, etc.

Do you know of any any third-party (commercial or open source) font engines available for the .net platform that offers such functionality?

Thanks

Comment: WPF has this kind of functionality.

Comment: WPF and DirectWrite offer similar functionality, but is limited to the extent that it can only do kerning with OpenType fonts for instance, whereas with Photoshop or Flex you can set parameters like kerning and all that with any font. I'm hoping to find a commercial solution that replicates the typography options that Adobe offers in Flex/Photoshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368038%28VS.85%29.aspx)? Not immediately available as .Net libraries but, could probably be [P/Invoked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx) into action.